# If string contains word replace entiree string

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
bank_38024032jr3020893 = bank_38024032jr3020893 + (call randomFunc) + 15;" \n
```

I want to to find and replace the `bank_38024032jr3020893` with let say `bank_hello` how would I go at doing that? `bank_38024032jr3020893` could change and I still want to be able to change it to whatever (bank_hello in the example).

I've found some good examples with regex but cant get that to work.

So what I want to is when it finds `bank_xxxOldxxx`it should replace that part with `bank_whateverIwant`

This is what I've tried:

```
string input2 = "bank_4556457 = bank_4556457 + (call randomFunc) + 15; \n"; 
string pattern2 = @"bank_";
string replace2 = "bank_55444";
string result2 = Regex.Replace(input2, pattern2, replace2);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

I understand that I cant grab the things after the "_" with that but not sure how to edit the code to fix my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on your console:

```
string input = ReadLine();
WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input,"test_(\\d|[a-zA-Z])+","NewTest123"));
ReadKey();
```

\d matches any number, and the '+' sign means that is matches as many occurrences possible.
You should take a look at: [Regular Expression in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: Hats off to you sir!